# Get multiple sensors readings

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, android-sensors

I want to read orientation AND magnetic field.

I use

```
if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.Orientation) 
{ ... } 

if (e.Sensor.Type == SensorType.MagneticField) 
{ ... }
```

and I tried

```
_sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.All), SensorDelay.Game);
```

and

```
_sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField), SensorDelay.Game);
```

and

```
_sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation), SensorDelay.Game);
```

and

```
_sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation | SensorType.MagneticField), SensorDelay.Game);
```

and

```
mOrientation = _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation);
mMagnetisch = _sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField);
if (mOrientation != null)
    _sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mOrientation, SensorDelay.Game);
if (mMagnetisch != null)
    _sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, mMagnetisch, SensorDelay.Game);
```

But each time **either** orientation **or** magneticfield shows. How to fix?

PS: My code stripped to the sensor part: http://pastebin.com/uXVRJmSq

Answer (score 1):

First, let your `Activity` implement `ISensorEventListener`. It looks like this:

```
public void OnAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, SensorStatus accuracy)
{
    // Do nothing.
}

public void OnSensorChanged(SensorEvent e)
{
    var sensor = e.Sensor;
    if (sensor.Type == SensorType.Orientation) {
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Orientation: " + e.Values[0], ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }else if (sensor.Type == SensorType.MagneticField) {
    Toast.MakeText(this, "MagneticField: " + e.Values[0], ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

Then, in the `Activity`'s `OnCreate()` method, register those two listeners.

```
var sensorManager = (SensorManager) GetSystemService(SensorService);
sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.Orientation), SensorDelay.Game);
sensorManager.RegisterListener(this, sensorManager.GetDefaultSensor(SensorType.MagneticField), SensorDelay.Game);
```

Comment: I found the solution myself. Your reply didn't solve it.

Comment: @Gewinn Could you post your solution? So I can know where I am missing and help other people as well.